# How to check ScyllaDB installed version?

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I have run nodetool version and showing  db version is 3.0.8 but if I am running scylla --version then it showing 2.1.1-0.20180325.cce455b1f. please help me which one is correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nodetool` reports its own version (related to the Cassandra version it was derived from). The correct version number is from `scylla --version`.

Comment: It means Scylla 2.1.1-0.20180325.cce455b referred cassandra 3.0.8  so my correct scylla version is 2.1.1 right and we can upgrade to scylla 2.x.y or latest?

Comment: Indeed, you have Scylla 2.1.1. The latest Scylla open-source version is already 3.0.*.

Answer (score 1):

`scylla --version` is one option. If you want to be sure what version Scylla started with (for example to be sure upgrade was successful), you can also run the following:

`curl -X GET "http://localhost:10000/storage_service/scylla_release_version"`